# type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, String>' is not a subtype of type '((Object?, Object?) => Object?)?'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am performing a post request and after filling the form, I get this

InternalLinkedHashMap<String, String>' is not a subtype of type '((Object?, Object?) => Object?)? error.

**This controller contains my post method**

```
class PostController extends GetxController {
final String url = ProjectApis.requestUrl;
ProjectApis _projectApis = ProjectApis();

Client _client = Client();

postRequest(userData, url) async {
  var response = await _client. Post(
    Uri.parse(url),
    body: JsonDecoder(userData),
    headers: _projectApis.headers,
  );
  return response;
}
```

}

**This is the data I am sending across after a user fills a form**

```
sendUserRequest() async {

var userData = {
  'title': _titleController.text,
  'author': _authorController.text,
  'index': _indexController.text,
  'date': _dateController.text,
  'return': _returnController.text,
  'name': _nameController.text,
};

var response =
    await _postController.postRequest(userData, ProjectApis.requestUrl);

var body = json.decode(response.body);
if (body['success']) {
  _clearForm();
  Get.snackbar(
    'Success',
    'Your request has been sent successfully',
    duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
  );
} else {
  Get.snackbar(
    'Error',
    'Something went wrong,
    duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
  );
}
```

}

**And the error message is**

_TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, String>' is not a subtype of type '((Object?, Object?) => Object?)?')

**The code breaks on** *(userData)*

I have read this [enter link description here](https://flutterhq.com/questions-and-answers/1417/type-liststring-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-string) but it does not seem to solve my problem please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it's decoded instead of being encoded

```dart
postRequest(userData, url) async {
  var response = await _client. Post(
    Uri.parse(url),
    body: JsonDecoder(userData), // issue here
    headers: _projectApis.headers,
  );
  return response;
}
```

Please change jsonDecoder to encoder like the following

```dart
postRequest(userData, url) async {
  var response = await _client. Post(
    Uri.parse(url),
    body: json.encode(userData), //change it to encoder
    headers: _projectApis.headers,
  );
  return response;
}
```